# How to view that CSV file properly?

Tags: json, excel, csv, google-sheets, export-to-csv

I'm wondering how to view that CSV file properly.. it looks like its a semicolons separated CSV file but i tried to view it on excel and imported it on google sheet and other viewers but i wasn't able to view it properly, so Is there anything i can do to view that file properly on excel or google sheet and export it then in a proper format?

https://drive.google.com/open?id=1ZnrUGP6RskzA1iI_o0kt0kFEl-PecsO6

any help in that matter would be appreciated.

Comment: What version of excel are you using? i was able to split it using text to columns on excel 2016

Comment: @Nick Thanks for the reply, i actually tried it on both 2016 and 2018 and couldnt separate the columns properly, please check that screenshot

Thanks Revathi, i already tried that but cant separate the columns properly, I tried it on both Excel 2016 and 2019 and google sheet. please check the attached screen

https://snag.gy/Lpswei.jpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Excel > Choose column

```
1.  Go to Data > Text to Columns  
2.  Choose Delimited > Next  
3.  Choose Semicolon > Next  
4.  Choose General or Text, whichever you prefer.  
5.  Click Finish.
```

Hope this helps! Tq

Edit: Attached file

[image]

Comment: Thanks Revathi, i already tried that but cant separate the columns properly, I tried it on both Excel 2016 and 2019 and google sheet. please check the attached screen

https://snag.gy/Lpswei.jpg

Comment: Hi Islam, I tried your file and it is working fine in Excel 2016. Can you please try again and see.

Comment: Thanks Revathi, I see now.. I was doing it via Data > From Text which was working fine for me on other sheets but some how it didnt work for that file but Text to Columns on Excel or Split text to Columns on google sheet fixed that issue, thanks so much again

Answer (score 0):

I second Revathi's answer and won't post again, only to add that I opened your file in a raw viewer and your EAN_Code field may be unrecoverable; what I assume should be a long numeric string has already been converted to scientific notation in the raw CSV.